# Tautologies in religious language discussion

Tags: philosophy-of-language, philosophy-of-religion, contemporary-philosophy

Influenced by Carnap and Wittgenstein, my view is that the disagreement between religious and non-religious people is mostly a semantic issue: the theistic and atheistic are referring to the same phenomena, only to disagree on the reference terminology. For example, consider the cosmological argument: the scientist and the preacher agree that the universe needs to have an uncaused cause, say X. The scientist refers to X as Big Bang, while the preacher refers to X as God.

I believe this idea is trivial; thus it is very likely that Wittgenstein or some of William James later contemporaries might have already talked about this issue. Can anyone point to me a specific passage from some famous philosopher having any idea similar to this?

Comment: I see a couple issues with this. First atheist and scientist are not synonyms. Second, scientists don't think the universe "needs" to have an uncaused cause. And third the big bang theory doesn't follow from a cosmological argument it's hypothesized from observations.

Comment: @Cell "The scientist" is a general term. Here I'm mentioning atheistic who often cite scientific results. Of course, there are different opinion in the scientific community, thus I don't deny that there are theistic scientists. However, the majority of scientist are Popperian, i.e., they believe in hypothesizing about cause and effect. Finally, the cosmological argument is an argument from induction, so it is a hypothesis from observation: everything has a cause, the universe is part of everything, and therefore the universe has a cause.

Comment: It's not merely a semantic issue because the theist and the atheist will disagree over what properties X has. Some e.g. think that you should pray to X. Or that X loves them. Atheists don't think this. So it's not just a semantic issue.

Comment: On the act of creation itself you may be right. But for atheists, the creator did all its work in a single instant, and never returned.

Comment: Consider Christianity and Islam. I'm not sure how it could be a semantic disagreement when one says Jesus died and one says he never did. Sorry, but this approach is ignorant of what the religions actually teach: don't worry everyone, it is easy to solve thousands of years of religious conflict by telling them they're all actually the same.

Comment: You have the right idea, except that the Big Bang is not the uncaused cause: rather, it definitely was caused by something.

Comment: I think you are referring to [Carnap's The Elimination of Metaphysics through Logical Analysis of Language](http://www.ditext.com/carnap/elimination.html). However, it is not Carnap's position that "theistic and atheistic are referring to the same phenomena, only disagree on the reference terminology", it is rather that theistic (more generally, metaphysical) terminology has no reference, it expresses "attitude towards life". According to late Wittgenstein, metaphysics misuses words (such as "cause") in a way that deprives them of their only (ordinary) meaning.

Comment: Welcome to the SE! A phenomenon that may shed light on you question is "magical thinking". For _Explanation_ humans have often invoked "demons" or "gods", or some other agency beyond compression. The theistic is quite happy to blame it all on God, in Science today "dark matter" could be seen as such, and as you noted many atheists will claim Science is the explanation (without further qualification) The similarity you see is that both _atheist_ and "preacher" takes something entirely on _faith_, however Science done properly (or popperly) tries to continually diminish the fraction of faith.

Comment: I'm not interested into phil of religion, but I totally disagree on the assertion that Big Bang and God are "the same thing with different names". God plays many roles - according to the religious point of view - and not only that of "creator". An I'm not sure that the BB is a "creator"... maybe only the first instant of creations.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How is the big bang not the whole of creation? At what point after the big bang is more creation required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but hopefully it provides additional references.

There was a similar project to remove disagreements "on the reference terminology", however, only among scientists, that A. J. Ayer credits with Otto Neurath: (page 82)

> It was his acceptance of this doctrine of physicalism that let Neurath to insist so much upon the unity of science. It was not only that he wished scientists of different branches to work together more than they do. He believed that, in spite of the differences in the professional vocabularies they were all fundamentally speaking the same language: they were all investigating the same physical world.

Otto Neurath may be a place to look for more information. Ayer provides a survey of the Vienna School in his article and additional sources might appear there.

If one considers that *anyone*, any sort of believer or non-believer, can practice science since science is objective, what believers would bring to science is additional semantic content. For example, Alvin Plantinga claims that the difference between a theistic approach and an atheistic approach to evolution is that the theist believes that evolution was "guided" and the atheist does not. In particular he writes this: (page 308)

> The scientific theory of evolution just as such is entirely compatible with the thought that God has guided and orchestrated the course of evolution, planned and directed it, in such a way as to achieve the ends he intends.

What this means is that from a semantic perspective, theism is likely able to engulf all scientific statements about "phenomena" adding to them divine guidance.

---

Ayer, A. J., Kneale, W. C., Paul, G. A., Pears, D. F., Strawson, P. F., & Warnock, G. J. (1957). The revolution in philosophy.

Plantinga, A. (2011). Where the conflict really lies: Science, religion, and naturalism. OUP USA.